# Customised URL problem with Google Apps

Tags: dns, google-workspace

I'm the administrator for our company's (standard) Google Apps account and i've tried customising our URL's for calendar, docs, sites, etc to shorter versions of the longer defaults.  These shorter links work fine from outside the office but won't work when i'm in the office, and i have to revert to the long default links.  Anyone got any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is the domain settings (CNAME records) have only been applied to a local DNS server, instead of the DNS server that is responsible for the domain (which you are wanting to use) and therefore the CNAME records were not propagated properly throughout the internet.

Comment: Cheers that worked.  Needed to add the URLs to our Server's DNS forward lookup zone settings as CNAME's :)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of companies use their website domain name internally for their Active Directory domain name -- this is a bad idea. However, if that's the situation you're in, then when you change your DNS settings outside of your internal network, you'll need to make those same changes to your internal DNS.